# What is the difference between the Auxiliary Equation and the Characteristic Equation? (ODEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When learning to solve homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients a, b, and c, the resulting polynomial ($ar^2 + br + c$) is referred to in my text as the *auxiliary equation*.

However, in the next section on solving homogeneous ODEs with variable coefficients (specifically dealing with an ODE of the form $at^2y'' + bty' + cy = 0$), the resulting polynomial
[$ar^2 + (b-a)r + c$] is referred to as the *characteristic equation*.

*What--if any--is the primary difference/distinction being made in the names of the two polynomials in these applications?*

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of these polynomials is the same: Find special solutions of the ODE from the roots of a polynomial. They are accordingly set up similarly: Insert a special function ($e^{rt}$ for the first case, $t^r$ for the second case) and obtain an algebraic expression that vanishes if and only if this special function is a solution of the ODE.

Note that what your textbook calls *auxiliary equation* is sometimes also called *characteristic equation*. The distinction is really only important on paper, since it is usually clear from the context which case is being discussed.

Comment: Is it improper to use the terms interchangeably?

Comment: You should stick to the same term (and possibly define it when you first use it) to avoid causing the confusion that you just experiences in others.